# Sample paytable for slots

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, recreational-mathematics

Could I get a sample paytable with at least $10$ combos for a $4$ reel slot machine with $6$ symbols on each reel with a house edge of $1 \%$?

Pay table is the combinations in which you win for example "Apple-Apple-Apple-Apple" gives you 50x gold, "Any-Any-Any-Apple" 2x gold and so on. House edge is the funds that the house doesn't give back to the players and keeps as profit instead.

My math sucks.

Comment: Could you explain the terms to those of us who are unfamiliar with gambling, i.e. 'sample paytable', 'house edge', etc?

Comment: Pay table is the combinations in which you win for example "Apple-Apple-Apple-Apple" gives you 50 gold, "Any-Any-Any-Apple" 1 gold and so on. House edge is the funds that the house doesn't give back to the players and keeps as profit instead.

Comment: Sorry what I meant to say is 2x multiplier, 50x multiplier since the number of coins you can bet is not fixed.

Comment: I suggest you change your question explaining all the terms in detail and what (if anything) you tried

Comment: Are you assuming that the symbols on the reels appear randomly? Or are you trying to emulate a modern computerized slot machine? The first case, the probabilities are set, and you fiddle with the payouts to achieve the desired house edge; in the latter, you can set the payouts however you like, then fiddle with the probabilities of each payout (and program the computer to choose among them accordingly).

Comment: It's a simple fair slot machine, every symbol has the same chance of falling.

Answer (score 1):

You have $6^4=1296$ possible outcomes.  You clearly are intended to assume all the choices come up equally.  To have exactly $1\%$ house advantage, after each combination comes up once, you need to pay out $0.99\cdot 1296=1283.04$, which we can round to $1283$  The simple way is to pick $10$ combinations and find $10$ numbers that add to $1283$ and assign one payoff to each combination.  An approach more like a real machine is to make a small prize, say $2$, for Apple, Apple, Any, Any.  That is $36$ combinations, so makes $72$ of your total payout.  There are lots of answers, but this should show you how to get to one.

Comment: +1. Nice. A note: For the "real machine" example, you may want something like "Apple, Apple, not-Apple, Any", since real machines tend to assign higher payouts to 3-in-a-row or 4-in-a-row combinations; you need a "not-Apple" as a c-c-c-combo breaker to make a (strictly) 2-in-a-row win. (Of course, "*at least* two Apples" is a perfectly good payout rule in and of itself.)

Answer (score 0):

OK, this solution assumes that I understand what you want (which I'm not too sure of). If all 6 values on each reel are unique (i.e. they don't repeat), then there's only $1$ way to get each of $10$ combinations, and obviously the probability of it is $\frac{1}{6^4}$. If you play $n$ times, the probability to get this specific combination $k$ times is just Binomial (assuming each sample is independent of the previous ones): $\binom{n}{k}(\frac{1}{6^4})^k (1-\frac{1}{6^4})^{n-k}$, so you expect that you'll get this combination on the average $\frac{n}{6^4}$. If the payoff of combination $j$ is $\pi_j$ and the cost of playing once is $r$, the expected payoff from combination $j$ would be
$$
R(j)=\frac{n(\pi_j-r)}{6^4}
$$
Does this answer your question?

Comment: They do repeat though, it's just that the machine isn't rigged so every symbol has the same chance of appearing, thanks for all the effort though.

Comment: If in $6$ slots 1 item appears twice and then 4 remaining items once, then the probability of each symbol can't be equal, if I got you right

Comment: Correct. This is a 5th graders math question, it's just that I haven't slept for a while and afraid to get the wrong answer. You couldn't have answered this more confusing if you tried.